# How many arrangements of the word "araspberry" with "ber" in the permutation?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I know araspberry has a total of $10$ letters with: aa, rrr, s, p, b, e, y. The classical question of arrangement would be $10!$ divided by the repeated letters, so it would be $$\frac{10!}{2!3!}$$ ($2$a's and $3$r's).

However, this problem requires putting "ber" together as one. I tried to put "ber" as one letter (x).

araspberry = arasp"x"ry, so we have to do $9!$ divided by the repeated letters $2$a and $2$r. However, $x$ includes $r$. In this case, how can we count the repeated letters? Should we divide by $2!2!$ ($2$a and $2$r) or still $2!3!$ ($2$a and $3$r no matter if $r$ is in $x$ or not)?

Comment: 2!2! . You can’t see the ‘r’ in ‘x’. Treat x as just a separate letter.

Comment: Notice that when you replace *ber* by *x*, you are left with eight characters, not nine: *a, a, r, r, p, s, y, x*.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the replies! So it should be 8!\2!2!

Answer (score 4):

One way to look at it is to remove $\boxed{ber}$ temporarily,
permute "araspry" in $\frac{7!}{2!2!}$ ways,
and insert $\boxed{ber}$ in the $8$ interstices in $-a-r-a-s-p-r-y-$

Comment: Thank you very much! I've never thought of it that way! So interesting! 8*7!\2!2! is actually the same as the 8! \2!2!

Comment: You're welcome ! As they say, there is more than one way to skin a cat ! $\;\;$ :)